How can I change the button label for lightning-file-upload?
I created a file upload function using lightning-file-upload, but the buttons display as Upload Files  I would like to change these labels to Sales Tax. Is there a way to do this?
    <lightning-file-upload label="Sales Tax"
                                class="hcp-upload slds-max-small-size_2-of-12 hcp-w9button" name="fileW9"
                                multiple="false" onuploadfinished={handleFileChange}
                                accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"></lightning-file-upload>

I tried overriding the button labels in lightning-file-upload using CSS, as shown below, but it didn't work. Can anyone please help on this?
    .hcp-w9button .slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    
    .hcp-w9button .slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button:after {
        content: 'Sales Tax';
        font-size: .8125rem;
        color: rgba(27, 82, 151, 1.0);
    }


Does this solve the problem ?

@Rohit No Not yet

I tried it too. It is not working. The best wayout would be to use slds markup instead of standard component.

The button label is "Upload Files" by default. Use the label attribute to add a descriptive label above the Upload Files button.

This question is similar to: Hot to change the button label for lightning-file-upload?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TusharJadav I tried on that approach also still the label is showing as "Upload File"

I know it might be a bit 'hacky', but have you tried adding '!important' as per the answer in the question Tushar has linked? There is a chance it is being overridden by the standard CSS classes if you haven't done this.

I've just tried Vitalii Dehnerys' (indeed hacky and in many cases to-avoid) workaround utilizing a static resource and it worked for me. SK2889, have you double checked the CSS (which you copied from Vitalii's response) got properly loaded? Note a regular CSS file as part of the LWC won't do. I agree that this is a duplicate of a question with acceptable answers.

When you set a label on the lightning-file-upload component then it will be shown the Label above the Upload Files button.
<lightning-file-upload label="Sales Tax" class="hcp-upload slds-max-small-size_2-of-12 hcp-w9button" name="fileW9"
            multiple="false" onuploadfinished={handleFileChange} accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.jpg,.jpeg,.png">
        </lightning-file-upload>

Output: 
If you want to change the button label then you need to change do using the CSS. First, create the .CSS file in your system with the below CSS.

/* remove the "Upload Files" text from the button of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button{
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

/* insert the text "Sales Tax" into the button of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button:after{
    content: 'Sales Tax' !important;
    font-size: .8125rem !important;
    color: rgba(27, 82, 151, 1.0) !important;
}

After that, upload this CSS file into the salesforce in Static Resource.

Now, In the LWC JS file import the platform resource loader library
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'; and static resource import fileupload from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fileupload';.
In the ConnectedCallback function load the CSS file.
        loadStyle(this, fileupload).then(() => {
            console.log('fileupload css loaded');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error to load fileupload css');
        });

Output: 
If you want to also update the Or drop files text then add the below CSS to the file and re-upload the file into the static resource.
/* remove the "or drop files" label from the right of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text{
    font-size: 0 !important;
}

/* insert the text "Or Drop Sales Tax" into the button of the lightning:input type file */
.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text:after{
    content: 'Or Drop Sales Tax' !important;
    font-size: .8125rem !important;
}


You could use following hack/concept:

add to html following div to contain style

<div lwc:dom="manual" lwc:ref="st"></div>

adjust renderedCallback function with
.slds-file-selector__button{ font-size:0rem; } .slds-file-selector__button::after{ color: red; font-size: 1rem; content: "W9" }

Idea is to hide existing text of a button and show new content in ::after area
